# stud.java:112: case, default, or '}' expected case1:System.out.println("enter name,rollno and percenta ge");

Tags: java

```
switch(c)
    {
        case1:System.out.println("enter name,rollno and percentage");
            c=String.parseString(sc.readLine());
            roll=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextInt());
            per=Integer.parseInt(getNumber());
            addatbegin(c,roll,per);
            break;
```

These are lines from 110 to 117
I don't know what's the error and there about 100 such errors in my switch case.

Comment: So how about posting the entire switch case? We can't say anything by seeing at a partial code.

Comment: "case" is a keyword, put a space after it.

Comment: @DaveNewton. O.o. How could I skip that. :(

Answer (score 2):

Separate the `case` from the value:

```
case1:
```

should be:

```
case 1:
```

Answer (score 2):

`case1` should be `case 1` your syntax is incorrect.

```
switch (c) {
    case 1:
        //Code here
        break;
    case 2:
        //Code here
        break;
    default:
        //Code here
        break;
    }
```

I guess you should have a look at [Switch Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: @titopo It is not mandatory at any level you add it to separate your cases. It is fine even if you do not specify break in default. I do it to have consistency.